# Need some help in creating a query in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cascading-deletes, audit-logging

I have 6 tables:

```
 Staff ( StaffID, Name )
 Product ( ProductID, Name )
 Faq ( FaqID, Question, Answer, ProductID* )
 Customer (CustomerID, Name, Email)
 Ticket ( TicketID, Problem, Status, Priority, LoggedTime, CustomerID* , ProductID* )
 TicketUpdate ( TicketUpdateID, Message, UpdateTime, TicketID* , StaffID* )
```

Question to be answered:
Given a Product ID, remove the record for that Product. When a product is removed all associated FAQ can stay in the database but should have a null reference in the ProductID field. The deletion of a product should, however, also remove any associated tickets and their updates. For completeness deleted tickets and their updates should be copied to an audit table or a set of tables that maintain historical data on products, their tickets and updates. (Hint: you will need to define a additional table or set or tables to maintain this audit information and automatically copy any deleted tickets and ticket updates when a product is deleted). Your audit table/s should record the user which requested the deletion and the timestamp for the deletion operation.

I have created additional maintain_audit table:

```
CREATE TABLE maintain_audit(
 TicketID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 TicketUpdateID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Message VARCHAR(1000),
 mdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 muser VARCHAR(128),
 PRIMARY KEY (TicketID, TicketUpdateID)
  );
```

Addittionally I have created  1 function and trigger:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maintain_audit()
      RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
      BEGIN
      INSERT INTO maintain_audit (TicketID,TicketUpdateID,Message,muser,mdate)
     (SELECT Ticket.ID,TicketUpdate.ID,Message,user,now() FROM Ticket, TicketUpdate WHERE             Ticket.ID=TicketUpdate.TicketID AND Ticket.ProductID = OLD.ID);
      RETURN OLD;
      END;
     $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql; 


 CREATE TRIGGER maintain_audit
     BEFORE DELETE
     ON Product
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE maintain_audit()

     DELETE FROM Product WHERE Product.ID=30;
```

When I run this all I get this :

```
    ERROR:  null value in column "productid" violates not-null constraint
   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE ONLY "public"."faq" SET "productid" = NULL WHERE $1     OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "productid""
```

GUYS,Could you help me in sorting out this problem?

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is triggers. Not sure what RDBMS you are using, but that's where you should start. I started from zero and had triggers up and running in a somewhat similar situation within an hour.

In case you don't already know, triggers do something after a specific type of query happens on a table, such as an insert, update or delete. You can do any type of query.

Another tip I would give you is not to delete anything, since that could break data integrity. You could just add an "active" boolean field, set active to false, then filter those out in most of your system's queries. Alternatively, you could just move the associated records out to a Products_archive table that has the same structure. Easy to do with:

```
select * into destination from source where 1=0
```

Still, I would do the work you need done using triggers because they're so automatic.

Answer (score 1):

1. create a foreign key for Ticket.product_id, and TicketUpdate.Ticket_id which has ON DELETE CASCADE. This will automatically delete all tickets and ticketupdates when you delete the product.
2. create an audit table for Product deleters with product_id, user and timestamp.  audit tables for ticket,ticketUpdate should mirror them exactly.
3. create a BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER for table Ticket which copies tickets to the audit table.
4. Do the same for TicketUpdate
5. Create an AFTER DETETE Trigger on Products to capture who requested a product be deleted in the product audit table.
6. In table FAQ create Product_id as a foreign key with ON DELETE SET NULL

Comment: Thanks David a lot!;-) That's very helpful!